# Shape detection and horizontal distance in pixels from the center

Tags: opencv

I'm very new on OpenCV and I'm still reading on it and experimenting, but how would I go about finding the 2 yellow objects in the following picture and extractive the horizontal distance in pixels from the center of the image ?

[image]

Note that the object are not necessarily yellow. I just used yellow ones right now for clarity (and maybe to make my life easier at first).

Any help appreciated ! Thanks.

Comment: which language you are using ? what did you try up to now ?

Comment: My preference is Go with GoCV (https://gocv.io/)

I tried a few of the OpenCV how to on the image trying to find a way to have it to detect the shape but without success.

Comment: Include details of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

This steps will helps you.

1. convert the image to HSV colour space and create a mask.  [check this tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/color-filter-python-opencv-tutorial/)
2. detect contour in a mask image.
3. compute center points by using

```py
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
(cx, cy) = (x+w/2, y+h//2)
```

4. compute the horizontal distance between center points.

```py
horizontal_pixel_distance = cx1-cx2
```

Comment: I'll give it a try Thanks.